# Flutter Animation Controller The argument type 'ExampleWidget' or 'this' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm following this guide for an animation: https://mightytechno.com/flutter-glow-pulse-animation/

When I go to use `this` it won't let me pass it. I can't compile and flutter clean does nothing. What object can I pass to get rid of this error?

[image]

```
void initState() {    
    getSharedPrefs();
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
    _animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
    _animation =  Tween(begin: 2.0,end: 15.0).animate(_animationController)..addListener((){
      setState(() {

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` fixed the issue:

`class Social4state extends State<UserProfilePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` to use this as vsync param. You can achieve this by using with keyword here is how:

`class Social4state extends State<UserProfilePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`